# A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Warning Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, codeigniter

im new in codeigniter

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()  
Filename: views/siswa_spp.php
Line Number: 39
```

and i cant solve that error, here is my controller :

```
function siswa($id_siswa)
  {
      $data['spp']            = $this->M_spp->detail_spp($id_siswa)->row();
      $data['temp']           = $this->M_spp->temp_spp($id_siswa)->row();
      $data['list']           = $this->M_spp->list_temp($id_siswa)->result();
      $data['bulan']          = $this->M_spp->listbulan($id_siswa);

      $this->load->view('includes/head');
      $this->load->view('includes/nav_header');
      $this->load->view('includes/nav_sidebar');
      $this->load->view('siswa_spp',$data);
      $this->load->view('includes/foot');
  }
```

my model :

```
function listbulan($id_siswa)
  {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('tb_spp');
    $this->db->where('id_siswa',$id_siswa);

    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
      $result = $query->result();
    }

    return $result;
  }
```

and my view :

```
<?php
   foreach ($bulan as $b) {
    echo $b->bulanPembayaran;
   }
?>
```

i dont know where the error in my code, and sorry for bad english

Comment: `$bulan` is not an array

Comment: since you only have 1 `foreach()` -> `foreach ($bulan as $b) {`, it would mean that `$bulan` is not an array.

Comment: Remove the if condition. `if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
      $result = $query->result();
    }` to `$result = $query->result();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check in your model if object found or not

```
function listbulan($id_siswa)
  {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('tb_spp');
    $this->db->where('id_siswa',$id_siswa);

    $query = $this->db->get();

    $result = false;
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
      $result = $query->result();
    }

    return $result;
  }
```

Check in your view as well.

```
<?php
   if($bulan){
      foreach ($bulan as $b) {
        echo $b->bulanPembayaran;
      }
   }
?>
```

Comment: To clarify, this not only checks that $bulan is set (I would probably throw an "&& (!empty) in there as well), this demonstrates that you're passing bulan as an object, not an array. If you want to call it in the view the way you're trying to, you would need to do something like: return get_object_vars($row = $query->row());

Answer (score 0):

check first $data['bulan'] is array or not

$this->load->view('siswa_spp',array("data" =>$data['bulan']));

pass like this in view..!!